# How to install MikroTik?

Tags: router

I need to install MikroTik , but I can't do it using Windows on virtual machine, because my CPU has no virtualization support and don't let me to install this.

How I can do it using for example terminal ?

Comment: As inferred by my other comment in your other question, you should be able to run a 32-bit Windows VM. That said, I would never do such a thing just for that GUI (and a router should have its own web server anyway). It should work fine for the purpose with just Wine: http://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=105552&p=558250&hilit=winbox+linux#p558250

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MikroTik) points out that the configuration is possible not only over `Winbox`. `SSH` and `telnet`are also supported. Maybe that's worth trying?

Furthermore it looks like `Winbox` is very well supported by [`wine`](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1881). You could install wine and then your `Winbox`

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Comment: Here is a native how to using openvpn and winbox: https://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2014/09/10/openvpn-server-setup-on-mikrotik-routeros/

Comment: This is not about VPN, it is about general MikroTik router configuration on Linux.